# EE Debug Toolbar: Installation Issues

Tags: debugging, ee-debug-toolbar

I can't seem to get EE Debug Toolbar installed on the latest version of ExpressionEngine (2.7.1) and EE Debug Toolbar 1.0 (22) RC1.

I've followed the [installation guide](https://github.com/mithra62/ee_debug_toolbar/wiki/Installation) as normal. In Addons > Modules it is listed as "Installed". In Addons > Extensions it is "Disabled" but I am unable to enable/install it. Clicking on Enable > Install > Submit doesn't produce any errors but at the same time it continues to be listed as "Disabled".

I've looked directly in the database at exp_extensions but it doesn't appear in the list. Has anyone else had any success on installing it with EE 2.7.1 and can shed any light on to how?

Comment: I dont have it running on 2.7, but...i had a similar issue on 2.6. I fixed it by re-uploading files to the theme folder again. But im sure youve already done this. Ive gone back to using the ee debugger and profiler anyway.

Comment: In this case I'm just working locally but I have uninstalled and re-installed a few times and even downloaded from both git and from the link on Devot-ee to be sure I had the most up to date version. I feel that it's been neglected a little and not been updated to work with the recent changes to EE 2.6+. Interesting to know you had it working on 2.6 though. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Im sure you have this set too....IMPORTANT: Make sure the ExpressionEngine configuration settings for template_debugging and show_profiler are equal to "y". Cant think of anything else to try.

Comment: Yes no problem there. I'm using the regular debug tools and profiler and they work fine. The problem in this case is that EE Debug Toolbar wont even activate in the Extensions section. It doesn't even show up in the database.